# Autosuggest textarea when press key on virtual keyboard using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on virtual keyboard with autosuggestion. I found hundreds of ready made example on internet. But all these autocomplete javascript code working only on keyboard key press. I'm very new to javascript. Can anyone help me to show autosuggest when i press mouse on a virtual keyboard button's key. My code is given below which is working good in keyboard key press.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "computer",
    "keyboard",
    "mouse",

  ];
  var minWordLength = 1;

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(' ');
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }
  $("#note-textarea")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }).autocomplete({
      minLength: minWordLength,
      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        var term = extractLast(request.term);
        if (term.length >= minWordLength) {
          response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, term));
        }
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(" ");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it and add relevant HTML and possible missing autocomplete library from CDN

Comment: Also .bind is superseded by .on

Comment: @mplungjan keyboard is here: gladwishes[dot]in

Comment: You are missing val18 in your keyboard

Comment: `.bind("keydown", function(event) {` is not triggered by a mousedown. Perhaps try on("input")

Comment: @mplungjan how to write on("input") event, will you please help me?

Comment: Change bind(..., to on("input",

Comment: @mplungjan on("input", not working

Comment: Worth a try....